# Find and change specific number in first part out of string and replace it

Tags: sql-server

I start to work on old project and there is sql server database column which stores articles numbers for example as follows:

```
11.1006.45
11.1006.46
11.1006.47
01.10012.11
01.10012.12
2.234.1
2.234.2
2.234.3
657.104324.32
```

Every number contains 3 parts. First part describe what producent it is and that's something i have to change when user choose diffrent number for specific producent. For example producent number 2 will be now 13 so according to our examples:

```
2.234.1
2.234.2
2.234.3
```

has to be done this way right now:

```
13.234.1
13.234.2
13.234.3
```

I am looking for sql query which would find all records where producent number is e.g 2.xxxxx and then replace to 13.xxxxx. I would like this query to be secure to avoid any issues with numbers replacments.Hope you understand what i ment.

Answer (score 1):

You could use this for update. '2. and 13.' could be any other string

```
DECLARE @SampleTable AS TABLE
(
   Version varchar(100)
)

INSERT INTO @SampleTable
VALUES
  ('11.1006.45'),
  ('11.1006.46'),
  ('11.1006.47'),
  ('01.10012.11'),
  ('01.10012.12'),
  ('2.234.1'),
  ('2.234.2'),
  ('2.234.3'),
  ('657.104324.32')


UPDATE @SampleTable
SET
   Version = '13.' + substring(Version, charindex('.', Version) + 1, len(Version) - charindex('.', Version))
WHERE Version LIKE '2.%'

SELECT * FROM @SampleTable st
```

Demo link: [Rextester](http://rextester.com/RPAKIA82818)

Comment: thanks for your contribution. Maybe stupid question but are you sure your code is 'secure enough' means will always do the job? Would like to avoid any mistakes on that step. Second what do you think about other people answers comparing o your solution, would like to pick 'the best one'

Comment: Of course I believe in my code logic. But you want to avoid any mistakes, then test carefully. You could try others and pick one by yourself :)

Comment: Will it always take first string (before 1st dot) right? Doesn't matter what is later or it also expect one additional second dot?

Comment: It always take first string. If you want second dot, then make another query.

Answer (score 0):

update t
set t.col=  replace(yourcol,substring(yourcol,1,charindex('.',yourcol,1),2)
from table t

this finds first character before first dot

```
substring(yourcol,1,charindex('.',yourcol,1)
```

then you use replace ,to replace it with whatever you need

Comment: could you provide whole aprt including replacment me to check please.

Comment: i dont get you what you are asking,try to replace with select and see if this is what you wanted

Answer (score 0):

You can use this query for multiple updation,

```
DECLARE @Temp AS TABLE
(
   ArtNo VARCHAR(100)
)

INSERT INTO @Temp
VALUES
  ('11.1006.45'),
  ('11.1006.46'),
  ('11.1006.47'),
  ('01.10012.11'),
  ('01.10012.12'),
  ('2.234.1'),
  ('2.234.2'),
  ('2.234.3'),
  ('657.104324.32')


UPDATE @Temp
SET ArtNo = CASE    WHEN SUBSTRING(ArtNo,1,CHARINDEX('.',ArtNo)-1) = '2' THEN STUFF(ArtNo,1,CHARINDEX('.',ArtNo)-1,'13')
                    WHEN SUBSTRING(ArtNo,1,CHARINDEX('.',ArtNo)-1) = '11' THEN STUFF(ArtNo,1,CHARINDEX('.',ArtNo)-1,'15')
                    ELSE  ArtNo
            END

SELECT * FROM @Temp
```